# Stripe doesn't return phone number on callback after checkout in Laravel

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I have added requirement to fill phone number in a checkout and it's asking for one, but when payment is successful I'm getting all the details in return in my callback, except phone number as it is being returned as null, what's wrong here?

Here is what I have in my checkout session and it requires for one in checkout

```
'phone_number_collection' => [
      'enabled' => true,
],
```

I'm using "stripe/stripe-php" package, so it's direct integration with Stripe.

Here's the checkout:
[image]

Here's what I get in return:

[image]

Comment: The community will likely need more information to understand what you're doing, and what you're seeing that is unexpected. Are you using Laravel Cashier, or the Laravel framework and integrating directly with Stripe? Where are you looking for the phone number when the session is completed? Is it present in the fields where Stripe says it will be located? https://stripe.com/docs/p

Comment: The phone number is in the Shipping details section there. You’re looking in `billing_details`.

Comment: I can confirm that the phone number is missing from my call back event object as well, the fields exist (ex: phone) however they are null instead of containing the expected value.  Both shipping and billing phone numbers are null.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why Checkout session doesn't return customer phone number, but there is another way of getting it.

You need to make a separate API request to the customer endpoint to get that info.

Read the docs: [https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/phone-numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/phone-numbers#after-session)

*After the session, you can retrieve customer phone numbers from the resulting Customer, or Checkout Session objects*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).